# Using if/else statement in awk

Tags: awk, last

Normally I can detect user's last logon time  if `last` return anything via below  function. My question is :  if `last` doesn't return anything then I want to look in the user's home directory date and time for the most recently modified file.

```
lastlogLatest() {
    last -n 1 "${userName}"  | awk ' {
    for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) {
        if ( $i ~ /Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun/ ) {
            j = 0
            str = ""
            for ( j=i; j<=NF;j++ ) {
                str = ( str ? (str FS $j):$j )
            }
            print str
            break
        }
    }
}'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following modification of your script appears to work:

```
lastlogLatest() {
    last -n 1 "${userName}"  | awk ' $1 != "wtmp" {
    for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) {
        if ( $i ~ /Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun/ ) {
            j = 0
            str = ""
            for ( j=i; j<=NF;j++ ) {
                str = ( str ? (str FS $j):$j )
            }
            print str
            break
        }
    }
}'
}
userName=somebody
lastlogin=$(lastlogLatest)
if [[ -z "$lastlogin" ]]; then
    echo "${userName} not found in lastlog"
   if cd /home/${userName} 2> /dev/null; then
      date -d "@$(find . -type f -printf '%T@\n' 2> /dev/null | sort -n | head -n1)"
   else
      echo "No home directory found for ${userName}" 1>$2
   fi
else
    echo "$lastlogin"
fi
```

I added a small tweak to the `awk` script that strips out the line telling us when the `wtmp` log begins, so that it doesn't pull that date out and assume it's for the specified user.

Also, note that this requires whichever user executing it to have permission to inspect the specified user's home directory and the files therein.

Comment: First of all , thank you so much. But I have a question too.  I have uploaded my script to https://hastebin.com/siqefusixi.bash    Now I have plugged (line 105)  your function  into the my bash script. Am I correct ?  So I am using `lastlogin` variable as output  printf command.

Comment: Well, what I do is I run the funciton and capture its output into the `lastlogin` variable.  If it's empty, that means nothing was found in the lastlog.  You could change function to reassign `lastlogin` rather than handling the output itself as written.  `lastlogin` will only have content if you _do not_ end up having to look at file modification timestamps.

Comment: OK. BTW,  Have you had a chance look my above uploaded bash script ? So Am I correct?

Comment: Since your original code would simply print the date, my answer is a drop-in replacement which will in summation print the date, yes.